# Obtaining domain contact records in php

Tags: php, whois

Which DNS records is for Domain owner Contact information ? if there is no such record then how can i get the owner information in php ?

Comment: This question isn't even remotely on topic.

Comment: Use a whois service. I think this should be moved to SuperUser or a more relavent site, though.

Comment: The OP is asking how to get the information in PHP. That's programming related.

Comment: RFC 2142 mandates abuse@domain as the abuse handling contact.  This is not universally supported, though.  There is a database at abuse.net which you can query; http://www.abuse.net/contact.phtml

Answer (score 5):

For most domains, the WHOIS data will contain the information you are looking for.  (Note, however, that some Top-Level Domains, such as `.to`, don't require the owner to publish full whois records, and some users pay a company for "Private Registration" so they don't need to include their direct contact information.)

You can use any of a number of PHP libraries to look up WHOIS information.

- The PHP Pear [Net_Whois](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Whois) package can do this.
- So can [phpWhois](http://www.phpwhois.org/).

Comment: Net_whois How this script get whois data , if from external source or API then I can't use it ? Do you know any free API service to get whois data and dns records ? I used NET_DNS2 to get dns records but i need domain owner contact information.

Comment: @RagniMunjal The same way that you need to provide the name of a DNS server to query, you need to provide the name of a WHOIS server to query.  If you download phpWhois and look at the code, you will see the list of WHOIS servers that it uses.  Most of them are the primary whois servers for each Top-Level Domain.

Comment: Looking at the code is always good. Look at it enough it becomes clearer then English. Honestly the best advice ever.

Answer (score 1):

Contact information isn't a DNS record, it's a [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) record.

You want to use something like http://www.phpwhois.org/